# Azure Durable Functions, Upgrading nuget package causes local testing to fail

Tags: upgrade, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a durable functions app that worked perfectly until I upgraded package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask from version 1.5.0 to 1.6.0.

Now running locally caused this error in the console:

```
[8/31/2018 9:35:58 PM] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[8/31/2018 9:35:58 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
[8/31/2018 9:35:58 PM] Stopping Host
```

I have made absolutlely no code changes. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I should also add that  it starts working again after reverting back to version 1.5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comment on our GitHub [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/420#issuecomment-417673679): If you're using the Functions V2 runtime, [breaking changes](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129) were introduced into the Functions V2 host. Durable Functions 1.6.0 accommodates those changes and must be used with version 2.0.12050.0 or higher of the Functions runtime. There's a new version of the Azure Functions Core Tools out to accommodate these changes as well.

If you want to use Durable Functions 1.6.0, you'll need to follow these steps:

- You will need to [update your Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#local-development-azure-functions-core-tools) to the latest version. (2.0.1-beta.37)
- If your app is built using Visual Studio, you need to update your Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions NuGet package to v1.0.19.
- You will need to [migrate to the new Functions V2 host.json schema](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json-(v2)).

If you want to stay with Durable Functions 1.5.0, you will need to pin your core tools to an older version, and in Azure, pin your FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION. More detailed information on pinning can be found in the [runtime release announcement.](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129)

If your Functions app is running on the V1 runtime, Durable Functions 1.6.0 should work without incident. (Please let us know if it's not, that means we need to fix something.)

- [Functions Runtime 2.0.12050-alpha release
  notes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases)
- [Functions Runtime 2.0.12050-alpha
  announcement](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129)
- [Durable Functions 1.6.0 release notes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/releases/tag/v1.6.0)

Comment: I tried your suggestions above But I still have the same error. Here are the packages I have installed:

Comment: "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.2.0"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.6.0"
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="2.0.0-beta4"
"Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.19"
"Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager" Version="1.6.0-preview"
"Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql" Version="1.13.0-preview"
"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="3.14.0"
"Polly" Version="6.0.1"
"System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.4.0"

Comment: Also, my host.json file is really simple:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "durableTask": {
    "HubName": "CopyDatabaseHub"
  }
}

Comment: Please read the wiki page on [migrating your host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json-(v2))

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you give me more information on your environment? Are you developing in V1 or V2, which IDE (VS? Code?), and which language?

Comment: Hi @katy-shimizu, My IDE is VS, language is c#, I presume V2 since I'm using V2 features. And my host.json file was modified as listed above per that very link [migrating your host.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json-(v2))

I should add that my code works great when deployed to Azure. This seems to be a local thing.

Comment: I FOUND IT! For VS I also had to upgrade the VS Extension "Azure Functions and Web Job Tools" to version 15.8.5023.0.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I have to answer.
There are several problems with durable functions v2.

With the latest package versions I can't run locally with VisualStudio IDE.
I tried and checked all the infos in the previous answer; "Azure Functions and Web Job Tools" is changed so I tried also versions 15.10.2009.0 and 15.8.5023.0

Most relevant problem is that at this point if I go down with package versions I can't use Newtonsoft because of versioning constraints.